# Returning a default value when looking up a pyspark map Column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `map` Column that I created using `pyspark.sql.functions.create_map`. I am performing some actions that require me to look up in this `map` column as shown below.

```py
lookup_map[col("col1")]
```

If a value does not exist in `lookup_map` column, I want it to return a default value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce` :

```
F.coalesce(lookup_map[col("col1")], F.lit("default"))
```

E.g.

For below map

```
mapping = {'1': 'value'}
mapping_expr = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in chain(*mapping.items())])
```

and Input DF:

[image: Input]

Output of

```
df.withColumn("value", F.coalesce(mapping_expr[F.col("id")], F.lit("x"))).show()
```

will be :

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it with `when` and `otherwise` functions by checking if `lookup_map[F.col("col")].isNotNull()`. Is there are different in performance in using `when` compared to using `coalesce`?

Comment: @BBloggsbott Probably Not as long as no udf is involved, but it's better to use well known function as it make the code more clean, most SQL people are aware of coalesce so they don't need to understand and one look is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using `when` and `otherwise`

```py
df.withColumn("col", when(col("mapColumn").getItem("key").isNotNull(),col("mapColumn").getItem("key")).otherwise(lit("DEFAULT_VALUE")))
```

There is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75481849/10715700) that suggests using `coalesce`. I haven't tried it and I am not sure if there are any difference in performance between them.